# semi-colon breaking mysql_query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm adding some html code to a database through a mysql_query. So, a basic query looks like this `$qry = "UPDATE Pages SET ".$column."='$value' WHERE id='$id'";`

If this is called, an actual query might look like this: `$qry = "UPDATE Pages SET content_en='<h1>This is a title</h1>' WHERE id='12'";` However, if the HTML code looks like this: `<h1 style='color:red;'>This is a title</h1>`, it'll break the query because of the semi-colon. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Don't add variables directly to query, escape string. Will encode variables and remove some vulnerabilities.

Comment: Prepared statements and sql parameters are the way to go.
**Never** build a query dynamically by concatenation - if you remember that concept it will save you a lot of headache in the future.

Comment: escape apostrophes around style => \'color: red; \'

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql escaping function over your content, like that :

```
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but you have to explain why it solves the problem(escape of single quotes).